# javascript / html won't display result of calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a heart rate zone calculator but it won't display the result of the calculation. I am new to javascript and html (coming from a java background) so any help and constructive criticism with that in mind is appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculateBMI()
        {
            //Obtain user inputs
            var Intensity = Number(document.getElementById("Intensity").value);
            var select_intensity = document.getElementById("select_intensity").value;
            var Age = Number(document.getElementById("Age").value);

            //Perform calculation based on intensity
            if (select_intensity == "Moderate") {
                var output =  (220-Age)*.5;
                var output2 = (220-Age)*.7;
            }


            if (select_intensity == "High Intensity") {
                output = (220 - Age) * .7;
                output2 = (220 - Age) * .85;

            }

            //Display result of calculation
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output " to " output2;


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heart Rate Zone Calculator</h1>
<p>Select Your Workout Intensity: <select type="multiple" id="Intensity">

        <option value="Moderate"selected="selected">Moderate</option>
        <option value="High Intensity">High Intensity</option>

    </select>
</p>
<p>Enter your age: <input type="text" id="Age"/>

</p>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Target Heart Rate" onclick="CalculateBMI();">
<h1>Your Target Heart Rate Zone Is: <span id="output" >?</span></h1>

</body>
```

Comment: You want to put your script inside the body, but after the HTML divs.

Comment: You're missing contenators (`+`) in `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output " to " output2;`

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions, unfortunately it is still not displaying the answer

Comment: I don't see an element with id `select_intensity`

Comment: also there is a scope issue. the second if and the print line wouldn't know anything about output and output2.

Comment: You need to close your input type="submit" with onclick="CalculateBMI()"/> It is not a styling command or JS function, so you do not need a semicolon at the end, just a forward slash. Including the above comments this code needs some reworking. Please refer to books for proper syntax use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your Javascript:

1) You have 2 intensity variables:

```
var Intensity = Number(document.getElementById("Intensity").value);
var select_intensity = document.getElementById("select_intensity").value;
```

`Intensity` refers to the correct element, but all of your code seems to only reference the `select_intensity` variable. Do this instead:

```
var select_intensity = document.getElementById("Intensity").value;
```

2) You forgot to place `+` around the `" to "` string for concatenation.

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output + " to " + output2;
```

Fixing both of those issues should cause it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
var Intensity = Number(document.getElementById("Intensity").value);
```

and change

```
var select_intensity = document.getElementById("Intensity").value;
```

to

```
var select_intensity = document.getElementById("select_intensity ").value;
```

Also change this

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output + " to " + output2;
```

This is finally how your code should look like

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculateBMI()
        {
            //Obtain user inputs
            //var Intensity = Number(document.getElementById("Intensity").value);
            var select_intensity = document.getElementById("Intensity").value;
            var Age = Number(document.getElementById("Age").value);

            //Perform calculation based on intensity
            if (select_intensity == "Moderate") {
                var output =  (220-Age)*.5;
                var output2 = (220-Age)*.7;
            }


            if (select_intensity == "High Intensity") {
                output = (220 - Age) * .7;
                output2 = (220 - Age) * .85;

            }

            //Display result of calculation
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output + " to " + output2;


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heart Rate Zone Calculator</h1>
<p>Select Your Workout Intensity: <select type="multiple" id="Intensity">

        <option value="Moderate"selected="selected">Moderate</option>
        <option value="High Intensity">High Intensity</option>

    </select>
</p>
<p>Enter your age: <input type="text" id="Age"/>

</p>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate Target Heart Rate" onclick="CalculateBMI();">
<h1>Your Target Heart Rate Zone Is: <span id="output" >?</span></h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

smaili's answer sums it up. I'd just like to add that as a new javascript programmer, you'll wanna be familiar with `console.log()` and F12 in your browser (unless you have a full-on JS dev IDE).

Comment: fortunately I have a license for all of the jetbrains IDEs, so i'm using webstorm at the moment